# The SECOND "Add Comment" button does nothing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, comments

I am commenting on an answer to a question I wrote. I clicked the "Add Comment" button under the answer and the edit window opened and I typed my comment, then when I click the SECOND "Add comment" button to the right of the edit box, it does nothing. Why.
I am using Firefox and I have commented on questions before, so I don't think it is a simple java-script issue as others have pointed out.

Comment: My javascript regularly goes.... "odd" on SO. First thing to try is emptying the browser cache... just to be sure.

Comment: What I often do is to perform a hard-refresh (shift-refresh).

Comment: Now I see the problem! I get only 600 characters for my comment. Below the edit box it shows "-816 characters left". How helpful is that - the minus sign is small and easily missed as a MINUS sign. Sigh.

Comment: Ok, How can I add clarification to my question without that 600 char limit?

Comment: I did clear the cache - no help

Comment: @Harvey, edit your question instead of adding a comment. The "- xxx characters left" is indeed very confusing. Something should be done for that.

Comment: I just changed my comment to a shorter one and "Add comment" worked fine. This is all really annoying. I went to the trouble of composing a clarification to my question and then spent two hours learning that it was too long. It seem my only options in continuing a Stackoverflow thread is to add a small comment or "Answer Your Question". Duh - really?!?!?

Comment: Oh, and yes it is limited to 600. Right here * it says I have 554 characters left. Yes I was 816 over (-816 characters left).

Comment: Sorry, O.K.W. now I see what you said to edit my original question. I misread that in my first reading.

Comment: 1416 character comment? I think that might mean it's more than just a comment...

Comment: Yah, but I didn't know how (or where) to add clarification to my question. I'm used to the many other forums and usenet groups where a thread is like an ongoing conversation. But now I have learned that I have to edit (and add to) my original question. I guess I can live with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go over the 600 character limit in a comment (or under 15), the "Add Comment" button simply does nothing. Sigh.

Comment: Actually it does 'blink' the character count message briefly. I do agree though that the cue is not obvious.

Comment: This always happens when it doesn't have enough characters. It appears to be a new change. The blink effect is also eastethically terrible =p

Comment: Perhaps the cue should be more obvious, such as: when clicked, the button disappears completely and is replaced with **NO!** (`font-size:200%`), until your character count is within the valid range.